# Using AngularJs directive to update input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update my weatherApp input field

```
<input type="number" class="hidden-input" ng-model="updatedWeather.SurfaceWind.Gust" winds></input>
```

by using an Angular Directive:

```
.directive('winds', windDirective);

function windDirective () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope : { ngModel : '=?'},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.bind('change', function () {
            console.log(ngModel);
            scope.$apply(setAnotherValue());
        });
        function setAnotherValue() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue("hello!");
            console.log(ngModel);
            ngModel.$render();
        }
    }
};
```

}

I declared the directive and controller before this, and everything seems to be running (successfully logging to console).  But for some reason, whenever I try and change my input field, the value defaults to 0, and nothing displays.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's your goal? Seems like you are trying to reset the input to "hello!" whenever it is changed. Maybe you could use `ng-change` to call a function whenever it changes and update `updatedWeather.SurfaceWind.Gust` there

Comment: My goal is to update wind gusts (value starting from 0) by adding it to the user supplied wind speed.  So the eventual solution would be having my gust input automatically adjusting to the windspeed, then allowing the user to add gusts (instead of adding gusts from 0, which doesn't really make sense).  So user wants 10mph winds, the gust input will automatically be set at 10mph, allowing the user to increase to >10mph.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding of what you want:

Demo: http://codepen.io/ozzieorca/pen/XXmJvV

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <wind>
    <div>
      <label>Wind Speed</label>
      <input type="number" ng-model="wind.speed">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Add Gust</label>
      <input type="number" ng-model="newGust">
      <button ng-click="wind.addGust(newGust)">Add</button>
    </div>
    Wind Speed: {{wind.speed}}<br>
    Gusts: {{wind.gusts | json}}<br>
    Total: {{wind.calculateTotal()}}
  </wind>
</div>
```

```
angular
  .module('myApp', []);

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('wind', wind);

function wind() {
  return  {
    restrict: 'EA',
    controller: WindController,
    controllerAs: 'wind',
    bindToController: true
  };

  function WindController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.speed = 0;
    vm.gusts = [];
    vm.addGust = addGust;
    vm.calculateTotal = calculateTotal;

    function addGust(val) {
      vm.gusts.push(val);
    }

    function calculateTotal(){
      return vm.speed + vm.gusts.reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0 );
    }
  }
}
```

I might still be a little confused. Let me know what you think. It sounds like you wanted the adding gusts and the total display in the same input. Maybe you could explain that a little more.